# Что делать если у пользователя закрыта пересылка сообщений в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telebot

Столкнулся с проблемой, написал тех поддержку, где я отвечаю пользователям по их айди, все работает прекрасно, но у некоторых пользователей запрещена пересылка сообщений, соответственно я не могу им ответить, думал сделать айди для каждой заявки, но есть 2 проблемы:

1. Смогу ли я отправить ответ в тех поддержке пользователю по заявке айди
2. Как сделать что бы у всех пользователей были разные заявки, а не одни и те же(либо повторяющиеся)